# is there a way to generate static obfuscated code in firefox extension

Tags: firefox-addon

My Firefox extension was rejected by [Mozilla Add-ons](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/). I got a reply like 
"We cannot allow the obfuscation the way you use it as it is impossible to generate the same obfuscated output. The obfuscator you use randomizes variable names in each run."

How can I generate static obfuscated code? Is it possible?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you share the part of code that is causing this error ?

Comment: I dont know from where i'm getting this error.. first i'm doing mininfy & then obfuscate for minified code.

Comment: Which code obfuscator you are using ? May be you can try Google's closure compiler http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home

Comment: earlier http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/Default.aspx, its dynamically generating vars.. Now http://www.jsobfuscate.com/index.php it should be okay now. i think :)

Comment: look for a way to seed the random number generator used by the obfuscater. perhaps replace the RNG with your own.

Answer (score 1):

I am a Mozilla Add-ons reviewer. Every add-on that is submitted has to be checked line by line to make sure there are no security, privacy or performance issues.

The obfuscated code, can not be checked. Minified or obfuscated code can only be accepted if the process can be reversed or reproduced.

By reproducing, I mean, add-on supplies the un-obfuscated file and the obfuscation process which if followed, reproduces the obfuscated file EXACTLY.

Otherwise, there is no way of checking the code. (Try reading any jquery.min.js and you will see how impossible it is)

Here is an example of a completely obfuscated code. How can it be checked?!

```
var _0xd1aa=["\x68\x74\x74\x70\x73\x3A\x2F\x2F\x77\x77\x77\x2E\x69\x72\x63\x74\x63\x2E\x63\x6F\x2E\x69\x6E\x2F\x65\x74\x69\x63\x6B\x65\x74\x69\x6E\x67\x2F\x6C\x6F\x67\x69\x6E\x48\x6F\x6D\x65\x2E\x6A\x73\x66","\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x61\x63\x65","\x6C\x6F\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E"];window[_0xd1aa[2]][_0xd1aa[1]](_0xd1aa[0]);
```

It is worth mentioning that such reviews often have to be carried out by Admin reviewers and that would add a great deal to the review waiting time.

I had a look at your code. It is minified. Frankly, minified code has no real benefit. It only makes it harder to review. It also makes it harder to maintain and debug for the developer.

Comment: Thanks for your best response.